# Generate and download archive zip with java

Tags: javascript, java

I have a zip file download function.
This function generates the ***.zip*** files on output folder in the server and downloads it.
Everything works perfectly!

However, testing with multi-users doens't work.
If 3 users attempt to generate the file at the same time, only one response is returned with the file for download.
The other 2 users are waiting forever and there is no result (no error occurs, the ajax call never returns).

My code:

JavaScript:

```
         $.fileDownload('\GenereteZipAction', {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            data: $('#formZip').serialize()
        }).done(function () {
            alert('Download successfully.');
            $('#modalZipLoading').modal('hide');
         })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('Error');
            $('#modalZipLoading').modal('hide');
         });
```

Java:

```
//get the name of user
userName = request.getParameter("user");

//get real path
String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

//create user folder
File fileOutput = new File(realPath+"/reports/output/"+userName);
fileOutput.mkdirs();

//generete reports in the user output folder
ReportHelper helper = new ReportHelper();
helper.genereteReports(fileOutput);

//set the reponse and... 
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Relatorios.zip");
//set the cookie for $.fileDownload go to done function 
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/"); 

//zip output user folder 
ZipHelper zipHelper = new ZipHelper ();
zipHelper.zipAllfiles(fileOutput);

//create and fill ZipOutputStream
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
zipHelper.fillZipOutputStream(zip);

//do download
zip.flush();

//close 
zip.close();

//delete folder
deleteDir(fileOutput);
```

My system is for more than five thousand users, so I'm sure more than two will use the report generation function at the same time.
I do not have much information of aplication server, just know it is IBM WebSphere.

I do not know if the problem is in my code, or the server that
not allowing multi-users. Every help is welcome!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into thread safety issues. This may help you: https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-term-thread-safe-mean-in-Java

`ReportHelper` or `ZipHelper` could be not thread-safe. `genereteReports` looks to be modifying something on the file system. I would look carefully at the code and ask yourself on each line, "what happens if something else tries to execute while my first thread is executing this line?"  I would suggest looking into `synchronized` calls and how they work.

Comment: It was exactly that my problem, I used global variables to zip the files, and those variables conflicted. Now I've set everything up by parameters and works perfectly. Thank you very much!!!!!!!